# access and display objects from an array

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cardplace = 1;
    
    var card = [
        {
            name: "Lord salazar"
            , atk: "12"
            , def: "3"
            , id: "1"
        }
        , {
            name: "Master manga"
            , atk: "8"
            , def: "10"
            , id: "2"
        }
];
    $("#draw").click(function drawcard() {
        var monster = card[Math.floor(Math.random() * card.length)];
        $('#' + cardplace).append('<div class="card"><div class="title"></div><div class="atk"></div><div class="def"></div>');
        $(".title").text(monster.name);
        $(".atk").text(monster.atk);
        $(".def").text(monster.def);
        cardplace = cardplace + 1;
        console.log(cardplace);
    });
    
  
    
    
});
```

```css
.card-place{
   width: 200px;
       height: 275px;
    background-color: saddlebrown;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    
}

.card{
    width: 180px;
    height: 255px;
    background-color: brown;
    overflow: auto; 
    padding: 10px;
}
.title{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  
}
.atk{
 background-color: burlywood;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
}
.def{
 background-color: burlywood;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button id="draw">draw</button>
    <div class="card-place" id="1">
 
    
    </div>
    <div class="card-place" id="2"></div>
    <div class="card-place" id="3"></div>
</body>
```

I would like to show a random object each time I click on the button with id #draw. The object appears, but it always replaces the other object in the variable monster. So I can't have different objects at the same time. Currently I have this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var cardplace = 1;
var monster = [];
var card = [
    {
        name: "monster 1"
        , atk: "12"
        , def: "3"
    }
    , {
        name: "monster 2"
        , atk: "8"
        , def: "10"
    }
];
$("#draw").click(function drawcard() {
    monster[cardplace] = card[Math.floor(Math.random() * card.length)];
    $('#' + cardplace).append('<div class="card"><div class="title"></div><div class="atk"></div><div class="def"></div>');
    $(".title").text(monster[cardplace].name);
    $(".atk").text(monster[cardplace].atk);
    $(".def").text(monster[cardplace].def);
    cardplace = cardplace + 1;
    console.log(cardplace);
});
});
```

here is the html

```
 <button id="draw">draw</button>
<div class="card-place" id="1">


</div>
<div class="card-place" id="2"></div>
<div class="card-place" id="3"></div>
```

Comment: if you need to add elements to your array you should probably use monster.push(object)

Comment: If you want to keep all value in monster, try push() instead of replacing the same monster. Edit: oops @gianni was faster :). Anyway, you can find more information about push here : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: Not sure what Question is?

Comment: I'd like the objects to be added to a div each time a click on a button. This doesn't work now cause the value of monster gets "replaced" each time i click on #draw.

Comment: There are only two objects within `card` array. Are you trying to create a copy of `card[Math.floor(Math.random() * card.length)]` and append that to `monster`? There would still only be two possible results of random selection from `card`.

Comment: Yes, I know there are only two possibilities. I want the objects to append to  div's with id's #1, #2 and #3. Right now, there only appears one of the objects three times in the div's.

Comment: _"I want the objects to append to div's with id's #1, #2 and #3."_ Where do you set the `html` of elements having `id` `#1`, `#2`, and `#3`? `$('#' + cardplace)` selects one element. Can you create a stacksnippet to demonstrate? Do you mean that at each of three clicks at `#draw`, `.append()` is called on different element?

Comment: Added the html code. And a snippet as well. In the snippet the code changed a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting each `.title`, `.atk` and `.def` element within `click` handler. You can create a variable to represent current `#1`, `#2` or `#3` element, then set `context` of `jQuery()` call to the current context.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cardplace = 1;

  var card = [{
    name: "Lord salazar",
    atk: "12",
    def: "3",
    id: "1"
  }, {
    name: "Master manga",
    atk: "8",
    def: "10",
    id: "2"
  }];
  $("#draw").click(function drawcard() {
    var monster = card[Math.floor(Math.random() * card.length)];
    var place = $('#' + cardplace);
    place.append('<div class="card"><div class="title"></div><div class="atk"></div><div class="def"></div>');
     // set `context` to `place` at each of `jQuery()` call below
    $(".title", place).text(monster.name);
    $(".atk", place).text(monster.atk);
    $(".def", place).text(monster.def);
    
    if (cardplace === $("[class|=card][id]").length) {
      cardplace = 1
    } else {
      cardplace += 1;
    };
  });

});
```

```css
.card-place {
  width: 200px;
  height: 275px;
  background-color: saddlebrown;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.card {
  width: 180px;
  height: 255px;
  background-color: brown;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.atk {
  background-color: burlywood;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}
.def {
  background-color: burlywood;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="draw">draw</button>
  <div class="card-place" id="1"></div>
  <div class="card-place" id="2"></div>
  <div class="card-place" id="3"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! I also have another question : How would you calculate the difference between the atk of the first object and the def of the second object later on?

Comment: @FrederikDelaet One approach would be to use `Array.prototype.reduce()` `var res = card.reduce((a, b) => a.atk - b.def)`. Note, description of requirement should be included within text of original Question, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if that will work in my case. What I would like to happen is when I click on the created object in div id #2 for example, than afterwards click on the object in div id #1. It shows the difference between the atk of the object in div id #2 and the defence of the object in div id #1.

Comment: _"What I would like to happen is when I click on the created object in div id #2 for example, than afterwards click on the object in div id #1. It shows the difference between the atk of the object in div id #2 and the defence of the object in div id #1"_ That is beyond scope of the original Question _"I would like to show a random object each time I click on the button with id #draw."_. Consider asking a new Question where that description of requirement is included within text of Question.